# XC8 builds font tables from top ROM

Tags: xc8

I wrote a barebone progran template in XC8 (1.37) that I use to develop and test new GLCD functions for the 18F family. Programming is done via a PICkit3. Since I need to quicky reprogram several times the code it is really important that programming is faster as much as possible.
Tipically, the code size is around 2K and it takes less than 10 sec to program,
Everiything is fine until I must use a font table, defined as:

```
const char font8[] = {....
```

Now, with just $400 bytes added, the compiler place the table at the ROM's end and the programming of 64K memory takes more than 1 minute.
Is there any way to avoid this?

I tried to manually limit the memory range in the MPLABX options, but this is annoying and a little unsafe (sometimes part of code is truncated).

Answer (score 0):

A while back I had to write some code for emissions testing, where I needed to copy data between extreme ends of RAM.  To do that I needed to specify the exact memory addresses.  You can also use the C extension __at() construct.  http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002053F.pdf#page=27

```
int scanMode __at(0x200);
const char keys[] __at(123) = { ’r’, ’s’, ’u’, ’d’};
int modify(int x) __at(0x1000) {
    return x * 2 + 3;
}
```